# how to deal with long-running model calculations in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am writing a quasi-MVC-style application. It has a GUI, a controller, and a back end that deals with all of the calculations and data accessing and stuff. This happened rather accidentally and I have no experience whatsoever with MVC, but I want to understand it more thoroughly.

So, the model has to do some lengthy calculations. How would this be handled in a traditional MVC approach? My approach is to spawn the long calculation in its own thread (so as to not block the GUI) and have the controller query it periodically about its current status so that it knows when to update the GUI.

In another case, the model is playing and recording some audio. Does this belong in the model? Should the model actively tell the controller what it is doing, or should it remain passive and be queried periodically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re considering a pure push-oriented MVC approach, the information route should be:

C → M → V

and between each component, you’d push a message that has a different semantic field; typically in a GUI app it’d be like this:

1. GUI event is captured and calls a Controller-owned callback.
2. Controller transforms GUI event-oriented semantics into Model command with parameters.
3. Model command is performed, asking related Views to (a) `update()` or (b) `update(data)`.

Using (a), the View has to poll the model for info. I don’t recommend this if you can avoid it, because it creates a tight coupling between the view and the model.

Using (b), the view’s `update()` method has a `data` parameter, which is sufficient for the view to perform its update.

In my opinion, the best solution would be this:

Have your model instantiate the calculation thread based on a controller event (or message). Then have the calculation thread notify the model of its progress. Indeed, the model may be interested to do some processing depending on the progress / state of your calculation thread.

When the model wants to notify its views (these may not be the same views depending on the calculations’ progress or other state dependency), have it notify interested view(s) of whatever model info you need to send them.

If your view(s) need to do some GUI rendering, depending on your GUI toolkit thread safety, you may need to use a delayed rendering method in your view update.

One convenient communication bus between the model and view is [Observable / Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You can also perform direct calls, however (this would create a tight coupling between the model and view).

Comment: could you comment on the Observable/Observer-thing you mentioned? I am sorry, but I am a complete newbie to this kind of thinking.

Comment: Rather than explicitely reference View instances in your model. you can use the Observable/Observer pattern . (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) . Make the view inherit Observer class (or have an internal member declared as Observer with a public method getObserver() in order for the model to access it). When the view is added to the model, the model adds it (or the result of view's getObserver()) to its observer list.when model wants to notify its views, it has only to call notifyObservers(data) to transmit data to views. Not knowing anything on how view will process data

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, polling should always be a solution of last resort. Why not have your model emit progress events and subscribe to them?

Comment: I do not want to have too many dependencies to Qt in the model, as it might have to be ported to a DSP later on. Besides, I tried this and it got very complex very fast and soon exceeded my brains capacity to grasp all the interactions.  
Still, this is a valid answer to my question, so thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess at what to do here (ported to a DSP? really? I suppose you mean the long-running process only) is that you should have the model be the data AND meta-data. Have one thread be a controller that is long-running, it updates the data and meta-data. Your gui threads are other controllers which when needed to construct a view, will look at the data and meta-data and wrangle this for the view.  The meta-data could be the current state of the long-running transformation or process, or it could include the location of the play-head and record-head.

Comment: In fact, the whole thing should be running on the DSP. However, I won't need any cross-platform compatibility, arbitrary file-IO or abstracted audio hardware interface on the DSP, so many things will get significantly simpler.

Answer (score -1):

If your business logic takes long time for processing, you could use several techniques to achieve your goal:
You can try using Tasks and async in your Actions. 
Or 
You can use WCF duplex call which will return your the async result when it's done
Or
you can try to use SignalR